# Send data from Singleton Class to JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, singleton

I'am developing Struts2 Application. There is a value in database table and I want to use that value in many different Jsp pages. For that I am using singleton class.

**DAO Class:**

```
public class TestDAO {

public String getServerName() throws DAOException {

    String findStatement = "SELECT name FROM classTest where value='1234';";

    PreparedStatement ps=null;
    ResultSet rs =null;

    try {
        
        ps=DBAccessManager.prepareStatement(findStatement);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        
        String name = rs.getString("name");
        return name;

    }catch{ //some text }
}
}
```

**Singleton Class:**

public class TestSingleton {

```
private static TestSingleton INSTANCE;
private String name;

private ServerSingleton() {
    try {
        setName(new TestDAO().getServerName());
    } catch (DAOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}

    public static TestSingleton getINSTANCE() {
    return INSTANCE;
}

public static void setINSTANCE(TestSingleton iNSTANCE) {
    INSTANCE = iNSTANCE;
}   

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

}
```

How can I use session in singleton class and read the session in JSP page

Answer (score 0):

In JSP pages you can get the value from the `valueStack`. Once you get hitted your action to the controller the action  context and `valueStack` are created by the Struts2 filter. You retrieve the value from the database using DAO and store it to the `valueSrack`. Note, that the `valueStack` is available not only in the controller but also in the view referencing a JSP page. In Struts2 the controller itself is exposed to the view via OGNL or EL. It is set on top of the `valueStack`.

So any changes to properties of the controller are reflected to JSP returned as a result with `dispatcher` result type which is default. If you use many JSP pages in many results then you have to retrieve the value from the database each time the request is made. Then you set the value to the property of controller.

Thus it is available to JSP returned as a result to the view via OGNL. All struts tags are supported to use OGNL in their attributes where you can write OGNL expressions or use EL.

It doesn't matter how you set the properties of the controller by the singleton object or prototype oblect the value is evaluated by OGNL expression. For it to work you provide your oblects with accessors and don't use a static context. Because the static context is turned off by default Struts2 configuration.

However if the objects are evaluated by many requests the singleton objects are shared by different threads and should be thread-safe.

If you use a session object which is implemented as a map in Struts2 and instance is already sinchronized. So you have only referencing a session scoped objects from the map which is available in the action context.